# SQL - Compare data from one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble finding a way to compare data from one table (Table1).

Part of the Table1

```
Date        ID        Item        
----        -------   -----
2017-06-30  90        2200
2017-06-30  150       1200
2017-06-30  150       1201
2017-06-30  150       1202 
2017-06-30  150       1203 
2017-06-30  150       1204
2017-07-31  150       1201
2017-07-31  150       1202
2017-07-31  150       1203
2017-07-31  150       1204
2017-07-31  150       1205
2017-07-31  90        2200
```

The result I would like to get is 1205 as this is a new item in following month. It would be also nice if I could get item that would not be anymore in the following month, ie 1200

** EDITED: The one thing I should mention is that Table1 has also different IDs in ID Column. So the main goal is to compare exact ID=150 (not 160 or 180). **

I will be grateful for any advice.

Thank you

Comment: @ADyson It's clear enough to me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.date = '2017-06-30' 
   AND y.item = x.item 
 WHERE x.date = '2017-07-31' 
   AND y.id IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y  
    ON y.id = x.id AND y.date = x.date - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
   AND y.item = x.item 
 WHERE x.date = '2017-07-31' 
   AND y.id IS NULL;
```

I would have left the remaining part as an exercise for the reader, but I see my plan has been scuppered.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will try to write it on my own and understand it. I have added also a line in which I can choose exact ID that I would like to check.

Comment: @michal2805 Note that there's actually a mechanism for expressing thanks on SO. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both "new" items in one month and "deleted" items:

```
select 'new', t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.item = t.item and
                        year(t2.date) = year(t.date - interval 1 month) and
                        month(t2.date) = month(t.date - interval 1 month)
                 )
union all
select 'deleted', t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.item = t.item and
                        year(t2.date) = year(t.date + interval 1 month) and
                        month(t2.date) = month(t.date + interval 1 month)
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

To select items that were not included in previous months or were retired in previous months...

```
select 'new item' as result_type, item
from MyTable a1
where not exists
(
select 1
from MyTable a2
where a1.item = a2.item
and a2.Date < a1.date -- change this to a date function to compare to previous month only
)
union all
select 'retired item' as result_type, item
from MyTable a1
where not exists
(
select 1
from MyTable a2
where a1.item = a2.item
and a2.Date > a1.date -- change this to a date function to compare to previous month only
)
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I will try to review this on my own. 

The one thing I should mention is that Table1 has also different IDs in ID Column.

So the main goal is to compare exact ID=150 (not 160 or 180).